# Java AES not decrypting Arabic

Tags: java, eclipse, encryption, aes

I'm working on Eclipse to encrypt and decrypt a string. I'm using the following functions:

```
private final static String ALGORITHM = "AES";


    public static String cipher(String secretKey, String data) throws Exception {



        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");

        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), secretKey.getBytes(), 128, 256);

        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);

        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), ALGORITHM);



        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);



        return toHex(cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes()));

    }


    public static String decipher(String secretKey, String data) throws Exception {



        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");

        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), secretKey.getBytes(), 128, 256);

        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);

        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), ALGORITHM);



        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);



        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);



        return new String(cipher.doFinal(toByte(data)));

    }


    private static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {

        int len = hexString.length()/2;



        byte[] result = new byte[len];



        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)

            result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).byteValue();

        return result;

    }


    public static String toHex(byte[] stringBytes) {

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2*stringBytes.length);



        for (int i = 0; i < stringBytes.length; i++) {

            result.append(HEX.charAt((stringBytes[i]>>4)&0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(stringBytes[i]&0x0f));

        }



        return result.toString();

    }
    private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";
```

The string that I'm working on contains English and Arabic characters. When I'm decrypting the string, the arabic characters are replaced by a question mark ( ? )

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Not 100% sure hence the comment, but I think that you need to specify the format of the string (UTF-8).

Comment: Arabic or not has nothing to do with encryption. Encryption only sees numbers (bytes) not their meaning to you. Wild guess: the console where you output the decryption does not support Unicode 16 and thus cannot show the characters properly. Also toHex and toByte methods are actually useless unless you use them for debugging the resulting bytes from encryption/decryption.

Comment: @m0skit0 see Jon Skeet's answer.

Comment: @npinti AFAIK you don't need specify string encoding if you use the default UTF-16 in both encryption/decryption.

Comment: @immibis I personally use the string encoding explicitly as UTF-8. I'm just saying that doesn't have to be the issue necessarily. I also understand that Jon Skeet is God, but I've seen him make mistakes as well (and get upvoted noneless xD).

Comment: @m0skit0 you don't specify encoding when encrypting because you encrypt bytes not strings - it's completely irrelevant to the actual encryption process whether those bytes came from a string, an image, a HW RNG, or whatever. This code does not specify the encoding when converting the string to bytes, so it gets whatever the default is, which probably can't encode Arabic. Also I have no idea about Jon Skeet being God, he just has the right answer.

Comment: @immibis *"you don't specify encoding when encrypting"* Erm, wrong. If you're encrypting a string you need to specify the encoding to get the byte array (`String#getBytes(CharSet)`), which is the case here (`cipher(String secretKey, String data)`).

Comment: @m0skit0: I'd argue that you really don't specify the encoding when encrypting - you specify it as a *preparatory* step before encrypting, and that's what's going wrong here. This is about separating the text to binary conversion from the encryption conversion - as per my answer. When you separate things out instead of doing multiple operations in one lump, it's easier to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you use `data.getBytes()` (and `secretKey.getBytes()`). This method uses the default encoding on your OS. For example in Western Europe on Windows this default is `Cp1252` which doesn't contain Arabic, and therefor converts unsupported characters to `?`.

You will need to use `data.getBytes("UTF-8)` and the same also when you create the String.

Bottomline: always be explicit with your character set!

Answer (score 3):

There are three separate transformations here:

- Unencrypted text to unencrypted bytes
- Unencrypted bytes to encrypted bytes
- Encrypted bytes to hex

... and the reverse, of course.

I *suspect* the problem is in the first step. Currently you're using `new String(byte[])` and `String.getBytes()`, both of which use the platform default encoding. That's almost *always* a bad idea. It's generally a good idea to use UTF-8 (e.g. using `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`) for *all* encoding and decoding, unless you have a good reason to use something else.

That's one starting point - but another is to look at *each* of those transformations separately, and work out where the data is being broken. Lots of diagnostics will help here.

I have a [blog post about precisely this sort of problem](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2014/01/20/diagnosing-issues-with-reversible-data-transformations.aspx), which goes into more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Well I made two adjustments and it worked :

- In the cipher function I wrote this : return toHex(cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8")));
- In the decipher function I wrote this :   return new String(cipher.doFinal(toByte(data)),"UTF-8");

Comment: You don't need to post this as an answer. If you want, edit the question and put it at the end of the question. (don't edit the code in the question if you do this, because then people can't see what the original problem was)

Comment: This answer is same as the 2 others already provided, I don't see why have 3 answers all the same.